# How to verify if Ids are present in each day within a period of x days?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, loops

The problem is the dataset has variable data rates per ID, I would like to filter out the IDs that do not have at least one data point per day.

I have a dataframe with IDs, dates, and data, in which I counted the daily sampling rate for each ID.

```
dfcounted = df.reset_index().groupby(['id', pd.Grouper(key='datetime', freq='D')]).count().reset_index()
```

Now, i have taken the first and last date of the dataframe, and created a dataframe of each day between the starting and ending dates:

```
# take dates
sdate = df['datetime'].min()   # start date
edate = df['datetime'].max()   # end date

# interval
delta = edate - sdate       # as timedelta

# empty list
dates = []

# store each date in list
for i in range(delta.days + 1):
    day = sdate + timedelta(days=i)
    dates.append(day)

# convert to dataframe 
dates = pd.DataFrame(data = dates, columns=["date"])
```

From here, I am lost on how to proceed. I have created a sample dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import random
import string

letters = string.ascii_lowercase
ids = random.choices(letters,k=100) 


date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(99), freq='D')

np.random.seed(seed=1111)
data = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': days,'ids': ids, 'data': data})
df = df.set_index('date')
```

With the sample df, i would expect to create a "results" df with only the ids that have data in each date.

Comment: so if an ID does not have a data point in the dates between `sdate` and `edate` you want to filter those out?

Comment: exactly! if an ID has no data on a given day, it should be filtered out

Comment: I think you could do this, please tell me if the logic makes sense - first find out the days between your start and end date. Then sort your dataframe and do a `groupby().cumcount` anything that doesn't equal the days between your start and end date you can filter that out.